# What type of regression to find the optimal advertising spending on different platforms?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, cross-validation, predictive-models, optimization

Lets say I have data regarding advertisement spending in different platforms (ie Google, social medias, physical billboards etc...) which results in customer "leads." Example would be something like 5000 spent on Google Ads which results in 500 leads (10 dollars per lead). Each ad sector would have different numbers resulting in some sectors being cheaper/produce more leads/more efficient etc...

My question is: What method of regression should I do to essentially answer the question: given X amount of money to spend on ads, how much should I put into each ad sector to produce the most leads?

Data wise, I'm assuming a quadratic shape for spending vs. dollars per lead for the different sectors otherwise it would just be 100% towards the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated if you just put everything through a regression then the most 'efficient' thing would be to put all money in the 'best' input. So you will have to do transformations like log or 1/x and feature engineering for any possible interactions.  Still a regression but interpretations would change. Then you just optimize that equation.

I think an issue you will run across is that any linear model will produce unreliable results when you 'optimize' your inputs since it will allow it to exceed the bounds they were fit on and put you in extrapolation land.

You could put constraints on that optimization to keep it in bounds. For example, if you don't have any data where you spent more than 5000 on facebook ads then don't allow it to exceed that.

In terms of other models you could try out a GAM or decision tree although I wouldn't know the best way to achieve what you want with a tree.